# Unity - Is it possible to add unit mass to a line renderer in unity 3d?

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

I have created a system whereby you can alter the position of points in game time, which are then connected with a line renderer to make a shape. However I then need to apply a mass to the line renderer that is specific to its length. I'm guessing this would involve something around adding a rigidbody to the line renderer component. However, I am not too sure how to got about this.
If anyone has any ideas it would be much appreciated.
Thanks

I am using to scripts to attach the line renderer, so any ideas how they could be altered for this?
script 1:

```
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using UnityEngine;

public class LineRenAttach : MonoBehaviour
{
    [SerializeField] private Transform[] position;
    [SerializeField] private BikeConnector connect;    
    private void Start()
    {
        connect.SetUpLine(position);
    }

  
}
```

script 2:

```
using UnityEngine;

public class Connector : MonoBehaviour
{
    private LineRenderer LineR;
    private Transform[] position;
    

    private void Awake()
    {
        LineR = GetComponent<LineRenderer>();
    }
    public void SetUpLine(Transform[] position)
    {
        LineR.positionCount = position.Length;
        this.position = position;
    }
    private void Update()
    {
        for (int i = 0; i < position.Length; i++)
        {
            LineR.SetPosition(i, position[i].position);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.